# Hibernate fetch data from two tables with one-to-one mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have two tables 'Person' and PersonDetail'. Now, I want to fetch data from these

two tables using HQL.

How should I go about it? Should I write separate queries, as in

[this](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/05/spring-crud-example-using-one-to-one.html#.V9JNFU194dU)

link, or should I write a join query??

How do I display data from these two tables on a single page??

**My working code**

/////////////////////////Main App//////////////////////////////

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWeb1Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWeb1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////IndexController////////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

////////////////////////PersonController///////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;


import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


import com.model.Person;
import com.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

     @Autowired
        public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
            this.personService = personService;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String list(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("persons", personService.listAllPersons());

            return "persons";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/{id}")
        public String showPerson(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));
            return "personshow";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/edit/{id}")
        public String edit(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/new")
        public String newPerson(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveProduct(Person person){
            personService.savePerson(person);
            return "redirect:/person/" + person.getId();
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/delete/{id}")
        public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
            personService.deletePerson(id);
            /*return "redirect:/products";*/
            return "personform";

        }


}
```

/////////////////////////////////Person//////////////////////////

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

/////////////////////////////PersonDetail/////////////////////////////

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonDetail", catalog = "myschema")
public class PersonDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String address;
    private Integer age;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Person person;

    public PersonDetail(){}

    public PersonDetail(Integer id,String address,Integer age)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.address=address;
        this.age=age;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign")
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
            @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }


}
```

/////////////////////////////PersonRepository//////////////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.model.Person;
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
}
```

//////////////////////////PersonDetailRepository/////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.model.PersonDetail;

public interface PersonDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonDetail, Integer>{

}
```

///////////////////////////////Service///////////////////////

```
package com.service;

import com.model.Person;



public interface PersonService {
     Iterable<Person> listAllPersons();

        Person getPersonById(Integer id);

        Person savePerson(Person person);

        void deletePerson(Integer id);
}
```

///////////////////////////////ServiceImpl/////////////////////

```
package com.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.model.Person;
import com.repository.PersonRepository;
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

      @Autowired
        public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
            this.personRepository = personRepository;
        }


    @Override
    public Iterable<Person> listAllPersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person savePerson(Person person) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
     @Override
        public void deletePerson(Integer id) {
            personRepository.delete(id);

        }
}
```

////////////////////////index.jsp/////////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>
    <!-- <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/persons}">Persons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/person/new}">Create Person</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div></nav></div>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
   <!--  <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////personform.jsp///////////////////////////

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>

     <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> 

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${person}" th:action="@{/person}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Person Id:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{address}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{age}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////persons//////////////////////

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>

   <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(persons)}">
        <h2>Person List</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Person Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Address</th>

                <th>View</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
                <td th:text="${person.id}"><a href="/person/${id}">Id</a></td>
                <td th:text="${person.id}">Person Id</td>
                <td th:text="${person.name}">description</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">Address</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetail.age}">Age</td>
                <!--   <td th:text="${product.price}">price</td> -->
                <td><a th:href="${ '/person/' + person.id}">View</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/person/edit/' + person.id}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/person/delete/' + person.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

//////////////////////////personshow/////////////////////////////

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Person Details</title>

    <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Person Id:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.id}">Person Id</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.name}">name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">address</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">age</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-09-09 15:37:49.866 ERROR 3836 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.model.Person.personDetail, referenced property unknown: com.model.PersonDetail.Person
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.SpringBootWeb1Application.main(SpringBootWeb1Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.model.Person.personDetail, referenced property unknown: com.model.PersonDetail.Person
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you specified all hibernate entity class in your bean configuration file... eg:  Person and PersonDetails.

Comment: I have used Spring Boot. There is no configuration file

Comment: As i can see the error . You dont have relation like ..com.model.Person.personDetail. Instead you have relation com.model.PersonDetail.person. Here in mapping you should have small p. as i can see in your PersonDetail entity.  private Person person;

Comment: where should I have the small 'p' ?

Comment: In the @Table(name = "PersonDetail" ??

Comment: When the above error comes ?? while starting server or while firing query

Comment: the error comes after the following lines

Comment: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-09-09 16:42:43.792 ERROR 4544 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122989/discussion-between-a-p-and-gokul).

Comment: that means there is something wrong with your configuration or Check relation of Person and PersonDetail.

Comment: The relation in one-to-one. I have specified that in both classes

Comment: In PersonDetail, I have mentioned @OneToOne(targetEntity=Person.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="id")

Comment: In person, I have mentioned @OneToOne(targetEntity=PersonDetail.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: I also tried replacing @JoinColumn(name="id") with @JoinTable(
         name="Person",
         joinColumns=
             @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id"),
         inverseJoinColumns=
             @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     ) I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String hql = "FROM PersonDetail pd JOIN pd.person";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<PersonDetail> personalDetailsList= query.list();
```

First Iterate above list then you can get person detail as below...

```
while()  // Iterate above list
{
    Person person=personalDetails.getPerson();
}
```

Comment: thanks. and should I include an additional jsp for displaying this combined data?? If I want to display it on an already-created-jsp,say persons.jsp, how do I do it?

Comment: you can do it in existing jsp ... just manipulate the fetched data as per your jsp required

Comment: Suppose I want to display the data from both tables in persons.jsp. How do I do it?

Comment: Instead of returning person you are better to return persondetail as per your relation of database. Person is reference of Persondetail. Then you can get Persondetail as well as person. Otherwise you will have to create a separate map then populate data accordingly... choose as you fell better.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: What changes have you done..... I am not talking to change you entity relation. Just change your return type of your function defined in spring . Return PersonDetails instead of Person when you are calling that HQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122973/discussion-between-a-p-and-gokul).

Comment: The error seems related to session . Check your project configuration.

Comment: I have used Spring Boot, so I did not need to specify any configuration

Comment: okay, I solved one of the errors. I added the @OneToOne aanotations on the private data members,instead of the getters.

Comment: Now, I have a new error : Unknown mappedBy in: com.model.Person.personDetail, referenced property unknown: com.model.PersonDetail.Person

Comment: I solved that mapping error. I had mentioned the name of the table as 'PersonDetail' , but its corresponding mapping was given like this : 'personDetail'.

Comment: Now, I am getting a new error :  Invalid property 'person' of bean class [com.model.Person]: Bean property 'person' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: I have given the appropriate mapping in the models and the tamplates. Can somebody suggest a solution to this?